# Repeating a directive with transclude that is different each time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

In my angular application I have several panels which have a shared structure, identical html.

Inside the panel the content and behavior changes, basically each one is a separate directive, let's call them panel-content.

This is the close to the solution I think is optimal but I have some architectural doubts.

Since I have directive (which has transclude true set):

```
<panel></panel>
```

It's template looks like this:

```
<div>
    Content
    <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
</div>
```

I have to repeat the panels

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="panel in panels">
        <panel>
            <panel-content></panel-content>
        </panel>
    </li>
</ul
```

This is all fine, but what would be a reasonably good way of "choosing" on each iteration which `<panel-content>` should I show?

Lets say I have a `panel.id` I can use.

I notice I can achieve it in several ways, I could do an ng-switch inside the `<panel-content>` view using the panel id, I could set up that the templateUrl of has a dynamic part and links to different URLs depending on the `panel.id`.

But for some reason, I am convinced I am missing something nicer more straightforward?

Please not that this architecture is not set in stone, if there is another structure that would better fit my needs please let me know.

So, the question again is, how do I choose? Or rather, who is responsible for choosing which `<panel-content>` should be displayed.

Comment: Is your content dependent on the panel.id ?

Comment: Yes. every panel-content is different, and I want to chose it depending on the `panel.id` or are you asking scope wise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you right, I would use `ng-include` in directive that changes each time the template by `id`:

Something like:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="panel in panels">
        <panel type-id="panel.id">
        </panel>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and Directive:

```
app.directive('panel', 
 function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<ng-include src="getTemplateUrl()"/>',


        link: function(scope,elem,attrs) {

           scope.getTemplateUrl = function() {

                var url;

                if(attrs.typeId !== undefined){
                    var url =  $rootScope.list_templates[attrs.typeId].value; // TODO: add validation
                  }


                return url;
            };
         }
      });
```

*app*

```
 $rootScope.list_templates = [
   { id: 0, value: 'partials/upcoming_0.html'},
   { id: 1, value: 'partials/upcoming_1.html'},
   { id: 2, value: 'partials/upcoming_2.html'}
];
```

Comment: Ok, looks reasonable and I think you understood me correctly. I'll play around with if for a second an I'll let you know.

Comment: What does this directive add on top of `ng-include`? Why not just use `<div ng-include="$root.listTemplates[$index].value">` instead of this `<panel>` directive? / @Trufa

Comment: @NewDev I need to include a directive not a template. I think that's what you're asking.

Comment: @Trufa, what is the distinction? This `<panel>` directive is just a very thin wrapper around the `ng-include` directive. If you just want to hide the details of the template URL, then I can understand that, but then I would place the actual URLs in a configurable service and use that.

Comment: @Maxim, my problem with this is that I need every panel to be a separate directive, the way you propose it, it is only one that shows different templates.

Comment: @NewDev let's continue here so we don't discuss in comments: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/74968/discussion-29560947?tab=general

Comment: @Maxim, thanks for the answer, this seems to be correct, but I think I might have to delete the question since I asked the wrong question. I apologize for that.

Comment: @Trufa you can't delete, because my answer was upvoted.

Comment: @MaximShoustin it doesn't make sense to delete anyways, because it might be helpful for others, it is correct for that question anyway. I will make another one.